# Tracing surrounding rectangle in manim

Tags: python, manim

The effect I'm looking for is equivalent to creating a rectangle around an object and uncreating it (in reverse) before the first animation is over. I faked the result by drawing another rectangle over the first with black stroke, but that creates new problems for my scene. Is there a more sensible way of doing this? Below is my fakery attempt.

```
class Test(Scene):
def construct(self):
    contfrac = MathTex("[2;4,1,2]")
    surrect1 = SurroundingRectangle(contfrac[0][1], buff=0.05, stroke_width=2.5)
    surrect1a = SurroundingRectangle(contfrac[0][1], buff=0.05, stroke_width=3.5, stroke_color=BLACK)

    anim1 = AnimationGroup(Create(surrect1), Create(surrect1a), lag_ratio=.15)
    
    self.play(Write(contfrac))
    self.play(anim1)
    self.remove(surrect1, surrect1a)
    self.wait()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for [the `Circumscribe` animation](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.animation.indication.Circumscribe.html).

Comment: Absolutely! Thank you for the quick reply!